# Use atomic functions in OpenACC

Tags: c++, openacc

I want to use atomic functions with OpenACC directives. What are the compile options of pgc++ that can help? Should I use a particular header file?

Comment: All atomic operations in OpenACC are provided by `#pragma acc atomic` directives. Your compiler needs to support V2.0 of the standard or later

Comment: I tried these directives but I get compilation errors. For                                             #pragma acc atomic                                                                                {res[i][i]=res[i][i]+x}, i have no compilation error, but for                                                              #pragma acc atomic                                                                                {res[i][i]=res[i][i]+x                                                                                        res[j][j]=res[j][j]+y}, I get  PGCC-S-0155-Invalid atomic expression

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check: are you using the right data? Per [this forum](http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=4652&sid=38ff929e6e3cabffae81719cf9a275bf) not all accelerators accept all data types and, possibly, not all data types can be accessed atomically. Table 13 at [this link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__feature-support-per-compute-capability) indicates that atomics on Nvidia seem to only be available for 32-bit integer and floating-point datatypes. 64-bit is available for compute capacities 6.x+.

You say your code looks like:

```
#pragma acc atomic
{
  res[i][i]=res[i][i]+x;
  res[j][j]=res[j][j]+y;
}
```

However, I don't think you can nest multiple atomics together like that. Try, instead:

```
#pragma acc atomic update
res[i][i]=res[i][i]+x;

#pragma acc atomic update
res[j][j]=res[j][j]+y;
```